# flotgraph using functions for conditional radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, conditional-statements, flot

I have a dataset where each node contains a date and a value.

I don't want flot to draw a circular point at ever value, especially if the value is zero

so in my graph's options I have:

```
points: {
          show: true,
          radius: 3
        },
```

but how do I have `radius: function (x) { return x.value>0?3:0 };

is this possible in flot, if so what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flot expects radius to be a number.  The simplest way to achieve this would be to create two series with the same color.  The first contains all the datapoints and `points: { show: false }` and the second contains only those datapoints where y > 0 and `lines: { show: false }`.